# Difference between df[df['col a']] and df['col a']?

Tags: python, pandas, list, nested

I'm new at coding and feel like to really understand it, I have to truly grasp the concepts.

Quality of life edit:

Why do we do df[df['col a']] == x? INSTEAD of df['col a'] == x? when making a search? I understand that on the second expression I would be looking at column names that equal X but I'd love to know what does the addition of making it a list (df[]) does for the code

I would love to know the difference between those two and what I am actually doing when I nest the column on a list.

any help is appreciated thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, `df[index]` selects slices from a dataframe based on an index.

Pandas supports [several different indexing methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html). The expression in your question chains two of them together. First, the inner index `df['col_a']` selects all values in column `col_a`. These are evaluated in a boolean expression that returns a series that is "masked" with True where the values in the column meet a condition and False elsewhere. The outer part then uses [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) to select all rows in the entire dataframe that meet this condition.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'column2': ['x', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'y']})

[In] df
[Out]
column1 column2
0       a       x
1       b       x
2       c       x
3       d       y
4       e       y
```

Selecting a single column:

```
[In] df['column2']
[Out] 
0    x
1    x
2    x
3    y
4    y
Name: column2, dtype: object
```

Creating a mask:

```
[In] df['column2'] == 'x'
[Out]
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
Name: column2, dtype: bool
```

Selecting all rows that have value `x` in column `column2`:

```
[In] df[df['column2'] == 'x']
[Out]
  column1 column2
0       a       x
1       b       x
2       c       x
```

Answer (score 0):

So we use `df[df['col a']== x]` instead of just `df['col a'] == x` because to optimize the dataframe itself you are escencially telling the data frame with `df['col a'] == x` that you want a bool of true false if the condition is met (you can try this on your df and will see that when you do not put it in the df[] that it only will list `df['col a'] == x` as a list of true and false). so it pandas will first say "What asking"? then it will say "You asked for X here is a series of True/False based on what you asked" and finally "You asked for all of the only True values of the series here is the dataframe the reflects only true"

Does that help clear up what it is doing? Basically just pandas trying to be as optimal as possible. As well as when you start learning more and more you can add multiple arguments `df[(df['col a'] == x) & (df['col b'] == y)]` which would be hard to write and keep together if you only did `df['col a']` for your serach

Comment: Hello ArchAngel I apologize for the incompleteness of the questions and Thank you for your answer.

You are right I'm trying to look up rows with certain conditions.

Now what I really want to know is what the addition of the df[] means coding wise, am I making a list of the results that equal something or is it just the required syntax to make the computer understand what I'm saying?

Why am I making a list of the results and can't for example do df['col a'] == x to get the same results?

Again I apologize for the lack of information!

Comment: No problem, I know its hard getting started especially when you don't know the lingo and proper "buzzwords" to get your question across

Comment: I updated my answer based on your updated question

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm glad there is people like you ArchAngel!! I can't upvote the answer because i don't have enough rep but that definitely solves it! Hope you have a great day!!!

Comment: No problem boss, glad I was able to help, keep studying and improving. Pretty soon you'll be out here answering my questions haha